# Select from all_tab_columns where table has > 0 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to search in a large DB a table that matches with a column name, but this table must have more than 0 rows.

Here is the query by the way:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tab_columns WHERE column_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%';
```

Comment: Please tell us are you looking for a `column` or a `table` name?

Answer (score 2):

You could use single query to filter names and get **actual** number of rows:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, cnt              
FROM all_tab_columns, XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' passing 
             (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(REPLACE(REPLACE(
             'select COUNT(*) AS cnt from <owner>.<table_name>', '<owner>', owner)
             , '<table_name>', table_name))) COLUMNS cnt INT)
WHERE column_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%' AND cnt > 0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=44b476da6478c36b7f1d76615ab3c07a)**

---

> Any chance this can be expanded/tweaked to yield the values of the first few rows for all tables?

Yes, by flattening row using JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*)) Oracle 19c:

```
-- generic approach Oracle 19c
SELECT owner, table_name, cnt, example             
FROM all_tab_columns, XMLTABLE('/ROWSET/ROW' passing 
                 (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                  'select COUNT(*) AS cnt,
                          MAX((SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(*)) 
                               FROM <owner>.<table_name> 
                               WHERE rownum < 10)  -- taking up to 10 rows as example
                              ) as example 
                          from <owner>.<table_name>', '<owner>', owner)
                 , '<table_name>', table_name))) 
                 COLUMNS cnt INT
                        , example VARCHAR2(1000))
WHERE column_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%'
      AND cnt > 0;
```

Demo contains hardcoded column list inside `JSON_OBJECT`. Oracle 19c and `JSON_OBJECT(*)` would allow any column list per table.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0d7cd5be399c7f4842970ae9d99187a3)**

How it works:

1. find all tables that have column named `'%ID_SUPPORT'`
2. run query per table using `dbms_xml_gen.getxmltype`
3. in sub query count the rows, flatten few rows an example to JSON
4. return rows that have at least one record table

Comment: Any chance this can be expanded/tweaked to yield the values of the first few rows for all tables?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty It is whole new question. As each table may have different column list it has to be converted to single column maybe JSON or XML

Comment: It probably is; but my idea is [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621705/sql-merge-tables-side-by-side-with-nothing-in-common): I'd like to add the tables side-by-side by just adding further columns to the "grand table" without any JOIN or other relationship (different "lenghts" of columns could be "levelled out" by NULLs). But maybe it's a silly question / idea... :(

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty The idea is NOT silly at all. Added some workaround that may be used as inspiration

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
SELECT * FROM all_tables WHERE num_rows > 0
  AND table_name in (SELECT table_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE column_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%')
```

Comment: Yes, It is, is table name, not column name. This is the point, all_tables has num_rows, and not all_tab_columns. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `num_rows` will only be as accurate as determined by the timing and parameters of the last analyze; it is possible this will miss some tables that have just had their first rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

If your DB is periodically analyzed the direct way is to use the following SQL :

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_tables t 
 WHERE t.table_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%'
   and t.num_rows > 0;
```

More precise way to determine is using the following :

```
declare
  v_val pls_integer := 0;
begin
  for c in (
            SELECT *
              FROM all_tables t
             WHERE t.table_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%'
           ) 
  loop  

    execute immediate 'select count(1) from '||c.owner||'.'||c.table_name into v_val;

    if v_val > 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line('Table Name : '||c.table_name||' with '||v_val||' rows ');
    end if;

  end loop;  
end;
```

I'm confused with the word `matches`. If you mean `column`, but not `table`, you may use the following routine to get the desired tables with columns whose names are like `ID_SUPPORT` :

```
declare
  v_val pls_integer := 0;
begin
  for c in (
            SELECT t.*
              FROM all_tab_columns c
              JOIN all_tables t on ( c.table_name = t.table_name )
             WHERE c.column_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%'
           ) 
  loop  

    execute immediate 'select count(1) from '||c.owner||'.'||c.table_name into v_val;

    if v_val > 0 then
     dbms_output.put_line('Table Name : '||c.table_name||' with '||v_val||' rows ');
    end if;

  end loop;  
end;
```

Comment: `table_name` != `column_name`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda re-read  again please "I need to search in a large DB `a table` that matches with a column name, but this table must have more than 0 rows."  So, OP looks for a table.

Comment: Please check your query one again: `SELECT *
  FROM all_tables t 
 WHERE t.table_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%'
   and t.num_rows > 0;`  **` WHERE t.table_name LIKE '%ID_SUPPORT%'`**